# Compactness of a Lie subgroup of SU(n)

Tags: differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Consider a Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak{g} \subset \mathfrak{su}(n)$ such that $G = \exp\mathfrak{g} \subset \mathrm{SU}(n)$ is Lie. Is $G$ a compact Lie group?

I'm thinking one can use Cartan's closed subgroup theorem in the opposite direction: since $G$ is a Lie subgroup, it is closed in $\mathrm{SU}(n)$. Then we use the fact that closed $\Leftrightarrow$ compact for Lie subgroups. However, I am not 100% sure if I can apply the theorem in this way.

Related questions:

[Is every Lie subgroup of $SU(2)$ closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2847563/is-every-lie-subgroup-of-su2-closed) (My question seems to be a generalization to arbitrary $n$, but the proof method in the answer seems too explicit to generalize.)

[Can a Compact Lie Group have a Non-Compact Lie Subgroup?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630750/can-a-compact-lie-group-have-a-non-compact-lie-subgroup) (I am not sure whether my above definition of Lie subgroup coincides with that of the counterexamples.)

Comment: But how do you know that $G$ is in fact a Lie group?  In general, a subgroup of a Lie group need not itself be a Lie group (e.g. line of irrational slope in a flat torus).

Comment: If $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie algebra, is it not always true that $\exp\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie group? [Of course, this is a particular class of all possible subgroups (some of which may indeed not be Lie), but it's the class I am particularly interested in for this question. Perhaps I should reword the title to be more explicit?]

Comment: No - my example is of this form (a line in $S^1 \times S^1$ is generated by a one-dimensional subalgebra of the Lie algebra $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Comment: I see. I suppose I misunderstood Lie's third theorem. If we explicitly required $G$ to be Lie, then would my argument hold?

Comment: It depends on your definition of a Lie subgroup. Incidentally, what you wrote makes no sense: "... such that $G = \exp\mathfrak{g} \subset \mathrm{SU}(n)$ is Lie."

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a beginner to the subject. Why does the statement make no sense? All I mean to say is that I have a *particular* Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ which generates a Lie group via $\exp$.

Comment: @Banachspacefan: Lie was a mathematician who dies over 100 years ago. It makes no sense to say that "$G$ is ... Lie." One can say, for instance, that $G$ is (isomorphic to) a Lie group, or that $G$ a Lie subgroup or whatever else you had in mind. Also, if you have a Lie group $G$ and its subgroup $H$, the sentence "$H$ is a Lie group" is rather ambiguous: It might mean that $H$ with its subspace topology is isomorphic to a Lie group  or that $H$   is isomorphic to a Lie group as an abstract group, etc.