# Lie subgroup of non-abelian compact Lie group is compact?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras, compact-manifolds

I need to decide if this statement is true or false:

" Every Lie subgroup of non-abelian compact Lie group is compact."

I think that it is false. I thought in a counterexample in which the center is discrete and infinite. Let $G=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}SU(2)$. By Tychonoff theorem $G$ is compact (since $SU(2)$ is compact). But since $Z(SU(2))\cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ (cyclic group of order two) then $Z(G)\cong \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ which is infinite and discrete. Therefore although $G$ is compact, its center (which is a closed Lie subgroup) is not compact. This example is right? Thanks!!

Comment: In what sense is $G$ a Lie group? Lie groups are usually finite-dimensional by definition, and the various infinite-dimensional generalizations can lose some of the standard properties.

Comment: It was a doubt that I had. There is some example finite dimensional?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630750/can-a-compact-lie-group-have-a-non-compact-lie-subgroup) for example.

Comment: In this example the torus is abelian. I was thinking that this statement is true but i don't know how prove it.

Comment: @KauêOrlandoPereira Note the ambiguity of weather "Lie subgroup" includes closed as a criteria; you might want to clarify that in your question. If you aren't requiring closure, you can embed the torus in $SO(4)$ for a nonabelian counterexample.